# Java gather user info from Kerberos ticket

Tags: java, single-sign-on, desktop-application, kerberos

My Java desktop application get a Kerberos ticket from Active Directory using the JAAS module `Krb5LoginModule`; this is the code:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", realmName);
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", realmAddress);
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", pathToFile);
LoginContext ctx = new LoginContext("SignedOnUserLoginContext");
ctx.login();
Subject signedOnUserSubject = ctx.getSubject();
```

And this is the module:

```
SignedOnUserLoginContext {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
      required
      useTicketCache=true
      doNotPrompt=true;
};
```

This code work correctly and I can single sign-on, but I don't know how to gather some user informations using this ticket, like the given name.

Anyone have some hint?

Answer (score 2):

From the subject, you can retrieve the signed-in principal:

```
Principal principal = signedOnUserSubject.getPrincipals().iterator().next();
```

Now you can get the principal name: `principal.getName()`

With this information you should be able to query the active directory to get more information about the signed-in user, e.g. given name, phone number, ...